# How to toggle classes off one element and on another after onclick

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css, lightning-design-system

I am creating a custom menu using the [Salesforce Lightning Design System Global Navigation with sub tabs](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-navigation/#Active-tab-with-Sub-Tabs)

```
<div class="slds-context-bar slds-context-bar_tabs">
    <div class="slds-context-bar__secondary">
            <div class="slds-context-bar__vertical-divider"></div>
            <ul class="slds-grid" role="tablist">

                <li aura:id="tab"
                    class="slds-context-bar__item slds-context-bar__item_tab slds-is-active slds-has-sub-tabs"
                    role="presentation">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" data-record-id="menuItem2"
                        class="slds-context-bar__label-action" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"
                        aria-controls="context-tab-panel-1" id="context-tab-id-1">
                        <span class="slds-indicator-container"></span>
                        <span class="slds-truncate">Menu Item 1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li aura:id="tab" class="slds-context-bar__item slds-context-bar__item_tab" role="presentation">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" data-record-id="menuItem2"
                        class="slds-context-bar__label-action" role="tab" aria-selected="false"
                        tabindex="-1" aria-controls="context-tab-panel-2" id="context-tab-id-2">
                        <span class="slds-indicator-container"></span>
                        <span class="slds-truncate">Menu Item 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have a JavaScript controller method which handles the `onclick` event on the `<a>` tag:

```
   handleClick: function (cmp, event, helper) {

        var tabs = cmp.find('tab');
        var currentTab = event.target.closest('[aura:id]');
        tabs.forEach(tab => { 
           $A.util.removeClass(tab, 'slds-is-active'); 
           $A.util.removeClass(tab, 'slds-has-sub-tabs');
        });
        $A.util.addClass(currentTab, 'slds-is-active');
        $A.util.addClass(currentTab, 'slds-has-sub-tabs');

        helper.changeTab(event.currentTarget.dataset.recordId);
    },
```

When the tab is clicked, I need to **remove** these css classes:

- `slds-is-active`
- `slds-has-sub-tabs`

From the `<li>` of the previously active tab, and then **add** the same classes to the `<li>` of the tab just clicked.

**Questions**

1. How am I meant to reference the previously selected tab, to be able to remove the CSS classes, when the event happens on a different `<a>` tag?
2. How am I meant to apply the CSS classes to the parent tag of the newly selected `<a>` tag?

Comment: What is the current the problem you are facing? Or are you just asking for generic advice?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to solve the above problem :) ... so I would like some advice on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple way to do this, just remove the classes from all the tabs, then add them to the new tab. The browser is smart enough to not perform a re-render until a script completes, so you should get decent performance.

```
var tabs = cmp.find('tab'), currentTab = event.target.closest('[aura:id]');
tabs.forEach(tab => { 
  $A.util.removeClass(tab.getElement(), 'slds-is-active'); 
  $A.util.removeClass(tab.getElement(), 'slds-has-sub-tabs');
});
$A.util.addClass(currentTab, 'slds-is-active');
$A.util.addClass(currentTab, 'slds-has-sub-tabs');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code, and this line fails without error `currentTab = event.target.closest('[aura:id]');`

Comment: OK, so doing `var currentTab = event.target.closest('li');` works. Now the `removeClass` method calls in the `forEach` don't work... any ideas?

Comment: @Robs Let me play with it; I didn't actually test this one before I wrote it :p

Comment: @Robs Okay, so... You need the source element to get the desired effect. I've updated the code to reflect this.